# Jgroups: is it required to use merge2 in LAN

Tags: jgroups

I am using `Jgroups` to cluster three machines in a LAN. All the machines are connected to single switch.
Is it required to use `merge2` in my configuration?
Is there any performance advantage that I can gain by removal of `merge2`?

Comment: Don't believe it's required(especially for a 3 node scenario) but I don't think there's any significant performance advantage to removing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, MERGE2 or MERGE3 are not required. There is a neglectable performance gain by removing it, but member won't be able to merge back, e.g. if the switch crashed or someone pulled the plug and reinserted it later.